# What `body!= body` in Jade template means?

Tags: express, pug

This question is related to using [Jade templates](http://jade-lang.com/) with [Express.js](http://expressjs.com/).

I know that when I write `layout.jade` that contains:

```
!!!
html
    body != body
        header
            h1 My header
```

When I call `res.render('index')` then my actual template is rendered to beginning of the `body`.

My question is this: what does `!= body` mean and how Jade/Express use that to determine the placement for my template inside the layout? I know that if I change `!= body` inside another element then the actual view is rendered there instead. Does anyone know where this feature is documented?

Comment: Would like some clarification on this one as well. Been on my mind.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I quote, from Jade's [documentation/guide:](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#readme)

> Code buffered by = is escaped by default for security, however to output unescaped return values you may use !=:
>
> > p!= aVarContainingMoreHTML

When using `res.render('index')` the rendered contents of `index.jade` (in your case) will be passed as a local variable to your layout file (`layout.jade`). The local variable is available as **body**. However, if we simply output the **body** local variable, it would be *escaped* (special characters will be encoded). Thus, by using !=, the contents of body will be outputted *unescaped*.

Check out: http://expressjs.com/guide.html#view-rendering

Comment: Awesome! Just the answer I was looking, but wasn't very obvious from the docs.